# To authorize an App Service to get keys from Key Vault, do I need to use the IAM blade or the Access Policies blade?

Tags: azure

I'm unclear about how I authorize an Azure App Service to get a key from Azure Key Vault using System Assigned Managed Service Identities. Do I use the IAM blade and give the App Service Identity the Reader role? Or do I got to the Access Policies blade and find the Principal for the App Services identity and give it key permissions? Or do I do both?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just need your managed identity to read data from inside the Key Vault, then you use the Access Policies blade.

The access policies blade controls access to reading the content of the vault. The IAM blade controls access for managing the Key Vault object its self in Azure.